# Collapse Bootstrap navbar on blur

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to get a navbar menu with multiple layers to collapse if a user is TABBING through the menu and eventually tabs out of the menu (menu loses focus). I've tried doing things like

```
$(.dropdown-toggle).blur(function () {.....
```

but haven't been able to get anything to work appropriately. Has anyone done this? According to bootstrap's collapsing content doc, they provide functionality for a button to collapse the content, but in theory, this should be a really simple script, no?

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#collapsing-content

Comment: Hey did you tried my answer  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$('.dropdown-toggle').focus(function(){});`
And for out of focus use `$('.dropdown-toggle').focusout(function(){});`

Also you can use .dropdown-toggle:focus {...} in your css to make what you want to archieve.

> The :focus pseudo class in CSS is used for styling an element that is
>   currently targeted by the keyboard, or activated by the mouse.

p.s i don't know if it was a TYPO but you are missing your `''` when selecting the `.dropdown-toggle` class with jquery

Comment: yeah it was just a typo in here, thanks i'll test this out and see if i can get it working

Comment: Just getting back to actually looking at what you responded, and perhaps I'm misunderstanding your response, but my question is how to collapse the navbar submenu when the user LOSES focus. the navbar operates just fine onFocus.

Comment: Check my anser for the reverse of focus you have to use focusout

Comment: Thanks, I did try focusout as well as blur with no luck. I'm going to keep moving things around and will update if I find a solution.

Comment: Post your code here because i can't understand what is happening if i dont have code. Update your answer and post html, css and js

Comment: Check out my answer, you ended up being right the real problem was where i was trying to detect the loss of focus. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using blur, though the suggested focusout would have worked just fine as well. The problem was that the tabbing was actually occuring on the a tag and I was trying to detect a loss of focus on the li level. Silly mistake but I figured I may not be the only one in the world with this problem.